# WebDriverException: An unknown server-side .. Original error: -[FBApplication resolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: appium, robotframework

i use appium 1.13.0
xcode 11

WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[FBApplication resolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c02c9370

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184ece37c  + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000184114528 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184edb828  + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184ed3d10  + 1380
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184db8ecc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5   WebDriverAgentLib                   0x0000000106758cc4 -[XCUIElement(FBUtilities) fb_snapshotWithAttributes] + 96
    6   WebDriverAgentLib                   0x000000010672a704 +[FBXPath writeXmlWithRootElement:indexPath:elementStore:includedAttributes:writer:] + 912
    7   WebDriverAgentLib                   0x0000000106729b08 +[FBXPath xmlRepresentationWithRootElement:writer:elementStore:query:] + 436
    8   WebDriverAgentLib                   0x0000000106728f58 +[FBXPath xmlStringWithRootElement:] + 108
    [ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]
...      0x0000000102737758 -[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:] + 596
    60  XCTest                              0x000000010269c440 -[XCTestDriver runTestsAndReturnError:] + 428
    61  XCTest                              0x0000000102722284 _XCTestMain + 2400
    62  WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner         0x00000001022538e8 -[_XCTRunnerAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] + 0
    63  WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner         0x00000001022537f0 _XCTRunnerRunTests + 0
    64  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184e76790  + 20
    65  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184e76060  + 288
    66  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184e73d70  + 1068
    67  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184d93e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    68  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000186c40f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
    69  UIKit                               0x000000018e41367c UIApplicationMain + 236
    70  WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner         0x0000000102253ab4 main + 192
    71  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001848b056c  + 4

Comment: most probably you have used some deprecated selector..please post the code to understand more about the issue

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: i dont know why it works on version 1.15 the problem is only in version 1.13 and the previous of this version

Comment: which code do you want me to share?